# How to display text randomly from a file based on a duration of time in php

Tags: javascript, php

i am searching for a php program that access the text from a file as a input and display the text randomly. the text should be change for each 5 seconds.
i am having the following code right now.

```
enter code here
<?php
$myfile=".txt";

$fp=fopen($myfile,'r');
$data=fread($fp,filesize($myfile));
$d=".";
$word[]=explode($d,$data);

$n=mt_rand(0,50);
print "$word[$n]";
fclose($fp);
?>
```

in above code the text is changing only when the page is refreshed. but the text needs to change each 5 seconds without refreshing the web page. how can i do it..

Comment: `without refreshing the web page. how i do it`: You do it Using JavaScript, not PHP

Comment: could you please sent that JavaScript that display the text randomly during some interval of time

Comment: Write the entire file into the webpage. for example, within some JS, `var jsdata = "<?php echo $data; ?>";`. Then do the explode and rand bit in js maybe using a `setInterval` callback.

Answer (score 0):

use the [sockets](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) 
 for doing this from php side... if you want to do this from client side use ajax

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function () 
    {
        location.reload();
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

This snippet will refresh the page every 5 seconds.